# JavaFX Scheduling and Concurrency with Tasks

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, scheduled-tasks, javafx-8

To preface, I am fairly new to programming in Java and JavaFX.

I wanted to make a scheduling button for my program that will call a function: `setSchedule()`.

I wanted the button to set a recurring task that will be called with a defined period in between calls.

I made a class called `CreateTask`. I have a function within `CreateTask` that returns a `Task<Void>`, that function is called `getTask()`.

When `setSchedule` is called:

```
CreateTask createTask = new CreateTask();
Task task = createTask.getTask();

bar.progressProperty().bind(uploadTask.progressProperty());
programStatusText.textProperty().bind(uploadTask.messageProperty());

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor sch = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
sch.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My program works great for one execution. The progress bar loads and my function is completed. The problem is that the task isn't called again.

I have tried researching why this happens and I haven't had any luck so far!

Comment: please post some code...

Comment: Take a look at [ScheduledService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).

Answer (score 2):

From the [Task docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html):

> a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused. See Service for a reusable Worker.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaFX I usually use TimeLine to do scheduled tasks. Something Like this

```
/**
 * Timeline to cycle background image after 10 seconds.
 */
private Timeline timelineBackground = new Timeline();


void backgroundTimer()
{
    // initialise the Timeline cycle to indefinite duration
    timelineBackground.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    // add KeyFrame with a duration of 30 seconds, executing onFinished when the time expires
    timelineBackground.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(30000), (actionEvent) ->
    {
        cycleBackground();
    }, null, null));
    // start the Timeline
    timelineBackground.play();
}

private void cycleBackground()
{
    imageView.setImage(images[((imageIndex == images.length) ? (imageIndex = 0) : imageIndex++ )]);
}
```

EDIT:
Added the source for the cycleBackground method to show that the teask is and should be trivial when executing on the JavaFX main thread as this was not clear from my original post, as pointed out by Jewelsea. Also noticed I included the previous version which needed to catch exceptions which is not required for the final version I used.

Comment: This is a great solution if the scheduled work happens very quickly and a poor solution if the scheduled work takes a long time.  For example, if a blocking I/O call occurs, that is not good as the UI will hang whilst the I/O is performed.  But if all that happens is changing an attribute of a node in the scene graph, that is good as that can occur very quickly and will not hang the UI.

Comment: True but I was assuming by the use of a progress bar in the OP example that they wanted to update the progress bar not do some heavy task. As shown in my trivial example, although I should have included cycleBackground() source to show that all it does is change the background to a new image from a preloaded image array, so no heavy processing at all, just a simple UI update which I believe should be done in the JavaFX main thread.